# Move local SVN repository

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN on Windows 7. I would like to move my local SVN repository from `C:/repository` to `D:/repository`. I have a working copy (with many subfolders) located at `C:/workingcopy`.

Can I simply move the `C:/repository` folder to the `D:/repository` location by cutting and pasting? Then, is it sufficient to right-click on the `C:/workingcopy` folder and select `TortoiseSVN > Relocate...` and point it from `file:///C:/repository` to `file:///D:/repository`?

Comment: Yep, that's it.  You can just try it by copying and pasting the folder there, then doing the relocate.  If everything works as usual (it should), just delete the original.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from [Moving and Removing Repositories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.moving-and-removing.html) (emphasis mine):

> Subversion repository data is wholly contained within the repository
>   directory. As such, **you can move a Subversion repository to some
>   other location on disk, rename a repository, copy a repository, or
>   delete a repository altogether using the tools provided by your
>   operating system for manipulating directories**
>   [...]
>
> Of course, **there's often still more to be done** when trying to cleanly
>   affect changes such as this. For example, you might need to update
>   your Subversion server configuration to point to the new location of a
>   relocated repository or to remove configuration bits for a now-deleted
>   repository. If you have automated processes that publish information
>   from or about your repositories, they may need to be updated. Hook
>   scripts might need to be reconfigured. Users may need to be notified. [...]

Since you don't have a server, short answer is "yes, that's enough".